# Why can I bind a reference to a member of a struct defined using #pragma pack, but not __attribute__(packed))?

Tags: c++, g++

Let's say I declare two of essentially the same structure, one using `#pragma pack(1)` and another using `__attribute__((packed))`, like so:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct S
{
  int a, b;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

struct __attribute__((packed)) T
{
  int a, b;
};
```

As far as I understand these should have equivalent semantics.  However, if I do

```
S s;

std::cin >> s.a >> s.b;
```

then this compiles just fine, whereas if I do

```
T t;

std::cin >> t.a >> t.b;
```

then I get a compiler error

```
error: cannot bind packed field ‘t.T::a’ to ‘int&’
```

This error on its own I guess makes sense, even if it's annoying to have to work around on a platform where there is actually no problem with this sort of addressing.  But why don't I get the same error with `S`?

Comment: Works ok with clang; fails with gcc - live - https://godbolt.org/z/5zvKMKnEv  have an up vote.

Comment: @RichardCritten Indeed! Google found the duplicate when I went looking for help ... it looks like the exact same problem and the answer there is about as good as it's going to get, IMHO. I'll be happy to reopen if given a reason why the Qs are significantly different.

Comment: @AdrianMole read the dup and I think it's a good an answer as their can be, given we are looking at compiler extensions.

Comment: This is also discussed in latter part of this bugtrack: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36566 Basically, as far as I can tell, whoever designed one language extension chose to make it permissible, which will result in crashing or other UB on systems that cannot deal with unaligned access and whoever designed the other language extension chose to make it restrictive, and thus safer but harder to use.

Comment: It is just an inherent gcc bug, which no one cares to address. Obviously, (despite duplicate's answer) end user expects them to behave the same way, and the fact that they do not is just annoying. Banning the reference to packed struct member makes no sense, but I bet, it is there to stay. That it is what it is, I am afraid - unless we finally have packed structs standardized

Comment: @SergeyA Strangely, you can get a reference by casting the lvalue to a reference explicitly, which demotes the error into a warning: `std::cin >> reinterpret_cast<int&>(t.a)`

Comment: @eerorika interesting, thanks for sharing! Just strengthens my belief that the limitation is artificial, and probably buggy.